# Entity_Token breaks token my tokens

Tags: entities

I've got an issue after I installed entity_token module (Drupal 7)

Now I can't really open admin interface in Drupal that contains tokens.

That is how tokens are displayed without entity_token
[image]

That what happens after I install this module
[image]

I've google a bit about it and what I only found is that:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1203018
https://www.drupal.org/node/1058912
https://www.drupal.org/project/token_tweaks - sounds like a module that fix this issue (which logically for me sounds really wrong, module that fix another module).

My question is what to do :)
Please suggest if I've to go with module or patch or there is better way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with decreasing Token's limit (see images below)

[image]